# Confusion Regarding Overriding Class Properties in Swift

Tags: swift, inheritance, properties, static

I have read the Swift docs and searched here, but I still am not sure about how to implement a class hierarchy where each subclass sets custom value for an inherited static property; that is:

1. Base class defines a static property: all instances share the same value.
2. Subclass overrides the static property: all instances share the same value, **which is different form that of the base class.**

Can the property be stored?

Also, How should I access the value of the property from within an instance method (regardless of the particular class), and get the correct value everytime? will the following code work?

```
class BaseClass 
{
    // To be overridden by subclasses:
    static var myStaticProperty = "Hello"

    func useTheStaticProperty()
    {
        // Should yield the value of the overridden property
        // when executed on instances of a subclass: 
        let propertyValue = self.dynamicType.myStaticProperty

        // (do something with the value)
    }
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You are so close to being there, except that you can't override a `static` property in a subclass — that is what it means to be `static`. So you'd have to use a `class` property, and that means it will have to be a computed property — Swift lacks stored `class` properties.

So:

```
class ClassA {
    class var thing : String {return "A"}
    func doYourThing() {
        print(type(of:self).thing)
    }
}
class ClassB : ClassA {
    override class var thing : String {return "B"}
}
```

And let's test it:

```
ClassA().doYourThing() // A
ClassB().doYourThing() // B
```

Comment: Thanks. So, if the class variable happens to contain some big dictionary read from file (that I can't afford to calculate every time), I'll have to set up a separate, private stored static variable for each subclass, store my dictionary there, and return its value in the overridden (computed) class porperty, right?

Comment: @NicolasMiari One way to work-around the _“class vars can't be stored properties”_ restriction is to put each class in its own file _(which you generally do anyway)_ and then create a file-scope stored-property var to back the class computed-property var, like this: `fileprivate static var _thingStorage : String`.  Then in your class, your computed-property becomes `override class var thing : String { return _thingStorage }`.

Comment: Your comment completes the accepted answer! @NicolasMiari

Comment: Would you mind updating this for Swift 4? (`dynamicType` does not compile anymore.) Then we could close https://stackoverflow.com/q/52670640/1187415 as duplicate of this one.

Comment: @MartinR No worries.