# Using an overriden static property during initialization

Tags: swift, cocoa, realm

I would like to create a class with a static property that subclasses can override, which would be used to initialize instances. So far, I've tried to accomplish this like this:

```
import Cocoa

class A: NSObject {
    class var staticProperty: String {
        return "A"
    }

    var property: String = A.staticProperty
}

class B: A {
    override class var staticProperty: String {
        return "B"
    }
}
```

This does not work, since `B().property` still returns `"A"`. How could I change this code so that `property` contains the value specified by the subclass? Any help would be appreciated!

**Edit**
I would like to initialize `property` with the value of `staticProperty`, so this could also look like this:

```
var property: SomeClass = SomeClass(A.staticProperty)
```

But then, this initialization should still use `"A"` for class A, and `"B"` for class B.

**Edit 2 (After @RakeshaShastri's comment)**
For my specific use-case, I need `property` to be stored (so not computed) and non-lazy.

**Edit 3**
In short, I'm trying to build a Realm model class which has a few to-many relationships to other models. For these models (which are quite similar), I'm trying to create a superclass which contains the shared functionality, amongst which is also the inverse relationship. Therefore, I want to have a static property which contains the key in the first model to either of the other models, and then initialize a LinkingObjects property using this key name. Since Realm does not allow this to be lazy or computed, I cannot use these functionalities here.

Comment: Closely related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35665831/1187415. The only difference is that the (to-be-overriden) static property is called from a function, not from another property as in your case.

Comment: @MartinR `self` cannot be used on stored properties. You'd still have to do the initialization in `init`. Thanks for the link. I used it to refactor my answer.

Comment: @RakeshaShastri: You can, if you make it `lazy` ...

Comment: @MartinR _whoops_ _facepalm_ You may post the answer. I'm removing mine.

Comment: @MartinR for my specific case, I unfortunately can't make the property lazy...

Comment: @Gori you've mentioned none of this in the problem you posted.

Comment: @RakeshaShastri I'm sorry, didn't realize that. I will update my post to include this info

Comment: @Gori then the answer for your question would be - **it can't be done**

Comment: @RakeshaShastri Hm that's too bad. Is it due to the fact that the overriden property is static? If that's the case, I'll go for the suggestion by João, as it seems to circumvent this

Comment: @Gori Well, if it solves your problem use it. This is why people are asked to post the **actual problem** they have instead of made up code which doesn't even mimic the problem properly.

Comment: @RakeshaShastri I think you're a bit overreacting here. My actual code would be way too extensive and I feel that the problem would not become clear enough. Again, I'm sorry for not explicitly stating that it should not be a lazy or computed property, but in my example code (which does in fact mimic the problem) it's neither lazy nor computed.

Comment: It would be interesting to know *why* the property cannot be lazy.

Comment: @MartinR I hope my explanation clarifies my specific case enough. If not, please tell me :)

Comment: @Gori: I have zero experience with Realm, so I cannot help here.

Comment: @MartinR No problem, thanks for helping making my question more clear! I realize now that it's quite strange to not know why I have these restrictions :)

Answer (score 1):

If you inherit from NSObject why not using it ?

```
import Cocoa

class A: NSObject {
    var property: String
    public override init() {
        let str = type(of: self).perform(#selector(getter: type(of: self).staticProperty))?.takeUnretainedValue() as! String
        property = str

    }

    @objc class var staticProperty: String {
        return "A"
    }

}

class B: A {
    override class var staticProperty: String {
        return "B"
    }
}
```

[image: playground output]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I need it to be a stored property. This way it's a computed property, right?

Comment: That's a complicated solution you came up with :) Unfortunately, I found out my problem cannot be solved in any way whatsoever...

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with this aproach

```
class A {
   var prop: String{
       return "A"
   }

 }

class B: A {
  override var prop: String{
      return "B"
   }
}

print(A().prop) // "PRINTS A"
print(B().prop) // "PRINTS B"
```

Answer (score 0):

`A.staticProperty` will use static dispatch and will always point to `A`'s class property. You need dynamic dispatch here, aka `type(of: self)`.

However, `self` needs an instance to work with, thus `var property: String = type(of: self.staticProperty` won't compile.

However, lazy properties can work around this limitation, so you could declare `property` as a lazy one:

```
class A: NSObject {
    class var staticProperty: String {
        return "A"
    }

    private(set) lazy var property: String = { type(of: self).staticProperty }()
}

class B: A {
    override class var staticProperty: String {
        return "B"
    }
}

print(B().property) // B
```

P.S. the `private(set)` part is just something I usually do, I rarely allow extrinsic factors to change my object.

**Update** As @MartinR has pointed out, lazy is not a choice for the OP. An alternative solution that doesn't use a lazy var is to use a "shadowing" property:

```
class A: NSObject {
    class var staticProperty: String {
        return "A"
    }

    private var _property: String?
    var property: String {
        get {
            return _property ?? type(of: self).staticProperty
        }
        set {
            _property = newValue
        }
    }
}

class B: A {
    override class var staticProperty: String {
        return "B"
    }
}

let b = B()
print(b.property)  // B
b.property = "B'"
print(b.property) // B'
```

Comment: A lazy property was suggested in the comments, to which OP replied *“For my specific use-case, I need property to be ... non-lazy.”* (I only wonder where that restriction comes from.)

Comment: Hmm... missed that :P Nonetheless, I'll keep my answer, maybe it will help someone else.

Comment: @MartinR actually, I think I found a solution for non-lazy people :) I mean really non-lazy, having to duplicate a property means more code to write :)

Comment: @Cristik I have added more info on my problem, as to why it cannot be lazy or computed (basically due to the fact that I'm using Realm)

Comment: @Gori check the updated answer, I added a solution that doesn't involve lazy vars. Involves another property, though...

Comment: @Cristik: Well, the full quote is *“I need property to be stored (so not computed) and non-lazy”*

Comment: @Cristik I'm starting to get a bad headache from this as well, guess I'll have to start thinking of another design... :)